# How do I find the earliest time in this array or string form?

Tags: javascript, arrays, time

Question related to JS, Array and Time

```
var x = [["12:10", "13:40"], ["14:23", "16:00"], ["10:00", "20:00"], .......]
```

Note that the first time will always be earlier than the second time and

in each of the arrays, there will always be 2 times no more or less.

This is in an array format.

How do I find the earliest time? For example, if you compare only the first 3 arrays, 10:00 will be the output as it is the earliest among the 3.

Comment: Try the following: `[["02:00","03:00"],["12:10", "13:40"], ["14:23", "16:00"], ["10:00", "20:00"]].flat().sort().shift()`.

Comment: please show the times for smaller than `'10:00'`.

Comment: `const smallest  = x.reduce(function(a, b) { return a[0] <= b[0] ? a : b; })[0];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, Javascript lacks a generic `min` function, on the bright side, it's easy to "polyfill":

```
const min = array => array.reduce((a, b) => a < b ? a : b)
```

And then you can simply do

```
minTime = min(yourArray.flat())
```

or

```
minTime = min(yourArray.map(x => x[0]))
```

(this assuming hours < 10 are written with a leading zero, e.g. `08:15`)